# Set AuthenticationEventPublisher in AuthorizationServerConfigurer

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I want to set a specific `AuthenticationEventPublisher` for the `AuthenticationManager` that deals with the OAuth client authentications.

I have seen that the `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer` sets the `ClientDetailsUserDetailsService` that is used in the `ProviderManager` that deals with the client authentications. I could not find a way though how to get the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` to set an `AuthenticationEventPublisher`.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig implements AuthorizationServerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.???;
    }
}
```